# JDE Data Dictionary

Tags: jde, data-dictionary

JDE EnterpriseOne 8.98.4.1 Data Dictionary?  I've used Databrowser to locate data items in F9210 - in this case Long Address data fields.  Now how do I xref this field into tables, views, forms and reports where it is utilized?

Any JDE Data Dictionary pointers would be HUGELY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The version i am currently using is 8.98.41; the same as you.

You could fast path into P980011, this brings up a JDE Standard App that can be used for cross referencing Data Dictionary items and its use in all objects.

If you were to do it the SQL/UTB way, it would be quite hard as event rules are stored in a BLOB column in one of the LocalSpec tables.